# SCORM 2004: Multi-SCO Course Not Writing Score

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I have a Scorm 2004 3rd Edition Multi-SCO course that is comprised of two SCOs. The first SCO is a simple Captivate course without any assessment/quiz. The 2nd SCO is an HTML/JS based assessment. The issue I am having is that upon passing the assessment, the score (cmi.score.raw) is not being written to the database. I know that it's not an issue with my SCORM wrapper (pipwerks). If I take the 2nd SCO and convert it to a single SCO and then pass the assessment, the score gets written. So, I am guessing that it's an issue with my manifest file? Here is the manifest:

```
      <metadata>
    <schema>ADL SCORM</schema>
    <schemaversion>2004 3rd Edition</schemaversion>
  </metadata>
  <organizations default="com.learning-technologies">
    <organization identifier="com.learning-technologies" structure="hierarchical" adlseq:objectivesGlobalToSystem="false">
      <title>Business Writing</title>
      <item identifier="sco1_item" identifierref="sco1_resource" isvisible="true">
        <title>Business Writing</title>
        <imsss:sequencing IDRef="common_seq_rules">
          <imsss:objectives>
            <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="sco1_satisified">
              <imsss:mapInfo readSatisfiedStatus="true" targetObjectiveID="com.learning-technologies.sco1_satisfied" writeSatisfiedStatus="true"/>
            </imsss:primaryObjective>
          </imsss:objectives>
        </imsss:sequencing>
        <adlnav:presentation>
          <adlnav:navigationInterface>
            <adlnav:hideLMSUI>previous</adlnav:hideLMSUI>
            <adlnav:hideLMSUI>continue</adlnav:hideLMSUI>
          </adlnav:navigationInterface>
        </adlnav:presentation>
      </item>
      <item identifier="sco2_item" identifierref="sco2_resource" isvisible="true">
        <title>Business Writing - Assessment</title>
        <imsss:sequencing IDRef="common_seq_rules">
          <imsss:sequencingRules>
            <imsss:preConditionRule>
              <imsss:ruleConditions conditionCombination="any">
                <imsss:ruleCondition condition="satisfied" operator="not" referencedObjective="previous_sco_satisfied"/>
                <imsss:ruleCondition condition="objectiveStatusKnown" operator="not" referencedObjective="previous_sco_satisfied"/>
              </imsss:ruleConditions>
              <imsss:ruleAction action="disabled"/>
            </imsss:preConditionRule>
          </imsss:sequencingRules>
          <imsss:objectives>
            <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="sco2_satisfied">
              <imsss:mapInfo readSatisfiedStatus="true" targetObjectiveID="com.learning-technologies.sco2_satisfied" writeSatisfiedStatus="true"/>
            </imsss:primaryObjective>
            <imsss:objective objectiveID="previous_sco_satisfied">
              <imsss:mapInfo readSatisfiedStatus="true" targetObjectiveID="com.learning-technologies.sco1_satisfied" writeSatisfiedStatus="false"/>
            </imsss:objective>
          </imsss:objectives>
        </imsss:sequencing>
      </item>
      <imsss:sequencing>
        <imsss:controlMode choice="true" flow="true"/>
      </imsss:sequencing>
    </organization>
  </organizations>
  <resources>
    <resource identifier="sco1_resource" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormType="sco" href="Business Writing v19a.htm">
      <file href="Business Writing v19a.htm"/>
    </resource>
    <resource identifier="sco2_resource" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormType="sco" href="Assessment\index.html">
      <file href="Assessment\index.html"/>
    </resource>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took awhile for someone to answer.  I just went thru this for someone on LinkedIn. "cmi.score.scaled" is the main one you'd want to make sure is getting set.

I have a Gist up in a similar fashion with an example of the prereq and ability to rollup the score properly.  https://gist.github.com/cybercussion/11192402

Also a sample CAM with QUnit Test. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47351904/samplecourse.zip

Edit:
Adding a Test to match the use case: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47351904/samplemultisco-intro-test.zip

First QUnit SCO test will only set cmi.completion_status, and cmi.success_status (completed/passed).
Second Qunit SCO will run 10 objectives/interactions and set a score of 0.75 (75%).
imsmanifest.xml updated to match the needs of a pre-test SCO followed by a quiz/test.

Thanks,
Mark